# Access DOM elements after ng-if becomes true

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a div with an `ng-if` attribute. The corresponding expression becomes true after a `$http` promise is resolved successfully.

The `div` contains a `ul` that in turn contains a `li` with an `ng-repeat`. List items are created from data returned by the `$http` call. The `ul` has a vertical scroll bar.

After all the list items are generated, I want to adjust the height of the `ul` so that the `ul` has a scroll bar and the window does not.

I have a function to do just that. It works when called from a window resize event handler. I can't figure out how to call it immediately after the list items are generated. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a directive for that:

```
.directive('adjustHeight', function ($timeout, $window) {
    function adjustHeight(elem) {
        // Do stuff - adjust the height
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var resizeListener = function (evt) {
                adjustHeight(elem);
            };

            /* Adjust height on window resize */
            $window.addEventListener('resize', resizeListener);

            /* Adjust height when data changes
             * (if necessary add an extra property for when being visible) */
            scope.$watchCollection('data', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue.length === oldValue.length) {
                    /* Maybe you don't need to re-adjust the height
                     * if the number of elements hasn't changed */
                    return;
                }

                /* Wrapping the function inside a $timeout will ensure that
                 * the code is executed after the next browser rendering
                 * (thus after the modified list has been processed by ngRepeat) */
                $timeout(function () { adjustHeight(elem); });
            });

            /* Make sure to clear the window-resize listener, 
             * once the element is removed */
            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                $window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeListener);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
<div ng-if="someCondition" adjust-height data="items">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.property}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I was going to suggest a directive as well. However, unless the method requires reuse a directive is probably overkill.

Comment: @joseym: I don't think how (or in what aspect) it could be an overkill. Besides reusaility, the main point here is encapsulation of functionality. If it is not wrapped in a directive, you should have code in the controller to attach an event to `window.onResize`, other code (possibly in the service) that would resize once the data is fetched, more inside the controller to watch for when the element mght be removed from the page in order to un-register the listener.

Comment: @joseym: This is really bad for a number of reasons (it might not seem so bad now, but once your app starts growing...): 1. DOM/window manipulation in the controller. 2. Code possibly scattered and not in one place. 3. Not declarative (you don't know what's going on by looking at the view. You have to search in the controller to find out what's going on). 4. Not testable. (I think it's a big part of what Angular was **not** designed to be :))

Comment: I used ExpertSystem's suggestion for $watchCollection. But I added it to the associated controller, instead of to a new directive.

Comment: I suppose you read the comments above, so _you've been warned_ :)

Comment: @ExpertSystem, I am in the process of creating a directive, as you suggest.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with Angular2: Not able to reach an element using jQuery right after *ngIf became true. My walk-around is:

```
setTimeout(() => { /* your code */ }, 0);
```

The code will be executed after the DOM element is available.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the function into the the same promise that populates your scope, only wrap it in `$timeout`.

It would look something like:

```
$http.get('/someUrl').success(function(res){
  $scope.data = res;
  $timeout(resizeFn);
});
```